# How can JavaFx's Path onRotate( ) be used?

Tags: path, javafx

I have a program that has a path variable that is put in a Pane.

```
    Path path = new Path();
    MoveTo moveTo = new MoveTo();
    moveTo.setX(60);
    moveTo.setY(60);

    LineTo lineTo = new LineTo();
    lineTo.setX(100);
    lineTo.setY(60);

    path.getElements().add(moveTo);
    path.getElements().add(lineTo);
    path.setStrokeWidth(5);
    path.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

    canvas.getChildren().addAll(path);
```

I then want that path to be able to be rotated. I see that javafx has a [onRotate](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#onRotateProperty) method but I can not get it to work. I don't see any one using it either.

What I have tried so far:

```
path.onRotate((ActionEvent e) -> { 
// do some stuff
});
```

but netBeans says it can not find the symbol meaning it can't find this method. What am I missing?

Just incase any one else is wondering these are my imports:

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

import javafx.event.EventHandler;

Comment: Check you have the correct import for ActionEvent (the JavaFX one, not the AWT one)

Comment: I added the imports I have. Good thought though @james_D

Comment: Are you aware that onRotate is a [touch based input handler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/touch_events.htm) and you need a touch screen (or touch pad) to use it?

Comment: Great question. I was not but at some point I will be adding a touch based interface, so I suppose it is still a valid question for later implementation.

Comment: Also onRotate is not a method of path, it is a property, so it's corresponding method would actually be `path.setOnRotate(event -> someAction())` where event will be an instance of RotateEvent (not ActionEvent).

Comment: If you aren't trying to handle touch based input now, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I will make a new question for what I am doing at this moment, as it is clearly not going to be answered by onRotate. However, @jewelsea do you have any implementation of touch events for onRotate?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65116/discussion-between-jewelsea-and-eckama).